# Create individual tabulated output from common data file with some totals calculated

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have pipe delimited text file named data.txt like ...

```
Kalpesh|100|1
Kalpesh|500|1
Ramesh|500|1
Ramesh|500|1
Ramesh|500|1
Naresh|500|1
Ganesh|500|1
Ganesh|500|1
Ganesh|500|1
Ganesh|500|1
```

I am using an `awk` script as follows:

```c
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN { ln=0;slno=0;pg=0; }
{
name=$1;
{
if (name !=x||ln > 50) #if same name repeates more than 50times then new page
{ 
tot=0;
pg++;
printf("\f");
print "PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY"
print "+==============================+"
print "|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |"
print "+==============================+"
ln=0;
}
if (name!=x)
slno=1;tot+=$2;
{
printf ("|%3s|%10s|%10.2f|%4d|\n",slno,$1,$2,$3,tot,$4);
ln++;
slno++;
x=name;
 }
}
} END {
print "================================"
print "Total for",$1,slno,tot
print "================================"
print "\f" }' data.txt
```

This is giving result like

```
PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|   Kalpesh|    100.00|   1|
|  2|   Kalpesh|    500.00|   1|

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|
|  2|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|
|  3|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Naresh|    500.00|   1|

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  2|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  3|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  4|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Ganesh 5 2000
================================
```

My desired output is like

```
PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|   Kalpesh|    100.00|   1|
|  2|   Kalpesh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Kalpesh 2 600
================================

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|
|  2|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|
|  3|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Ramesh 3 1500
================================

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Naresh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Naresh 1 500
================================

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  2|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  3|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  4|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Ganesh 5 2000
================================
```

Comment: Are all the names unique? What is the third field `Nos`?

Comment: How many times during month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT:

[Ed Mortons answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568810/396144) is better, please use that.

---

```bsh
awk 'function print_entry(a,b,c,d) {
    k=split(c, ce, " ")
    split(d, dn, " ")
    for(i=1; i<=k; i++) {
        if(i%50==1) printf("\f%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",
            "PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY",
            "+==============================+",
            "|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |",
            "+==============================+")
        printf("|%3s|%10s|%10.2f|%4d|\n",i,a,ce[i],dn[i])
    }
    print "================================"
    print "Total for",a,k,b
    print "================================"
    printf("\f")
}
BEGIN {FS="|"}
{
    if($1==name) {
        total+=$2
        entry=(entry " " $2)
        nos=(nos " " $3)
    }
    else {
        if(name) print_entry(name,total,entry,nos)
        name=$1
        total=$2
        entry=$2
        nos=$3
    }
}
END {if(name) print_entry(name,total,entry,nos)}' data.txt
```

The main logic:

- Gather info relating to a name (`$1`)

  - `total` sums together each `$2` entry
  - `entry` keeps a list of each `$2` entry
  - `nos` keeps a list of each `$3` entry
- Each time the name changes, print the collected info

  - Splitting the `$2` entry list, gives the number of entries `k` for that name, also the `$3` list is split (it should have the same number of entries)
  - Starting from 1 (`i=1`), print each entry
  - If `i mod 50` is `1` print a header – this will print a new header every fifty entries
  - Then print the total

---

- The use of the function `print_entry` keeps the main action cleaner & easier to read, also it is used again in the `END` action, so defining it as a function saves repeating it

Comment: Can you explain thr answer. Whether it can be done without creating function ?

Comment: Updated with a description, also some minor changes to the script. It would be possible to do without the function definitions, but it will look messy and provide no benefit.

Comment: Why ed Mortons solution not working where first column is number. Thanks for function example i have seen this first time.

Comment: @KalpeshBhoj there is nothing in my solution that cares whether your first column is a number or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
$1 != prev {
    if ( NR>1 ) {
        prtTail()
    }
    prtHead()
    srval = 0
    tot   = 0
    prev  = $1
}
{
    tot += $2
    printf "|%3s|%10s|%10.2f|%4d|\n", ++srval, $1, $2, $3
}
END { prtTail() }

function prtHead() {
    print "PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY"
    print "+==============================+"
    print "|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |"
    print "+==============================+"
}

function prtTail() {
    print "================================"
    printf "Total for %s %d %d\n", prev, srval, tot
    print "================================"
    print ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|   Kalpesh|    100.00|   1|
|  2|   Kalpesh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Kalpesh 2 600
================================

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|
|  2|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|
|  3|    Ramesh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Ramesh 3 1500
================================

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Naresh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Naresh 1 500
================================

PERSONS HAVING OUTSTANDING ADVANCE SALARY
+==============================+
|Sr.|   name   |Amount Rs.|Nos |
+==============================+
|  1|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  2|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  3|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
|  4|    Ganesh|    500.00|   1|
================================
Total for Ganesh 4 2000
================================
```

Comment: One thing: OP wants a new header when the name appears more than 50 times. Thanks for this post, I see now that my answer was rather inefficient.

Comment: Yeah I saw something about that in their code but figured if they needed help with that part they'd have included it in their example.